# Confidence Interval for Normal Distribution - R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I want to calculate a confidence interval for a vector of normally distributed values in R. Doing this manually would not be too big of a hassle but surely there is an inbuilt function for this. I can't seem to find one though. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "confidence interval for a vector of normally distributed values". Do you want the CI for an estimate of the distribution mean?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a function for this, but a simple way to do this is to fit a model with intercept only and extract the confidence interval from that with the `confint` function.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(20)
m <- lm(x~1)

confint(m)
                2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.236892 0.6179398
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no a built-in function for precisely this and only this purpose. I guess the reason is that it really is very easy to compute manually. Let, as in the @bobbel's answer,

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(20)
```

Then one way to extract the interval would be

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
# [1] -0.2368920  0.6179398
# attr(,"conf.level")
# [1] 0.95
```

which is not a bad idea as often you will want to do the test anyway. As to get the interval alone, you are going to need to define your own function, e.g.,

```
normConfInt <- function(x, alpha = 0.05)
  mean(x) + qt(1 - alpha / 2, length(x) - 1) * sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)) * c(-1, 1)
normConfInt(x)
# [1] -0.2368920  0.6179398
```